# How to compile and run java program on different jdks/jre through command line?

Tags: java, java-8, jvm

I have 2 different versions of java as below

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241
and
C:\Program Files\Java\open-jdk-1.8
```

`JAVA_HOME` is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241` and my java program was compiled with `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241.`

Is below correct if I want to to RUN compiled HelloWorld at C:\workspace 
 with open jdk located at C:\Program Files\Java\open-jdk-1.8 as below

```
C:\workspace\src>"C:\Program Files\Java\open-jdk-1.8\bin\java" HelloWorld
```

Comment: No. First set a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. Then `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -cp c:\workspace HelloWorld` - Note you specify the classname. Not the path to the class.

Comment: thank you. is C:\Program Files\Java\open-jdk-1.8\bin\java -cp HelloWorld -> is this correct? what is -cp?

Comment: There is a space in your path. You must quote it. Or use the eight character form. Also cp is classpath (and needs to be the workspace folder). So no. That is not correct.

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Java\open-jdk-1.8\bin\java"  HelloWorld

Comment: corrected it. but why is -cp needed?

Comment: Thought you wanted to specify `c:\workspace`... that is why. I assumed you didn't necessarily want to be in `c:\workspace`. Alternatively, set `CLASSPATH` (the environment variable). Same thing. Try `java -help` to see supported command line options, and what they mean.

Comment: The primary answer is, the value of the `JAVA_HOME` variable is irrelevant to Java, so when you invoke a java command from a specific JDK with an absolute path, the command will use its own JDK, so `"C:\Program Files\Java\open-jdk-1.8\bin\java" HelloWorld` is sufficient to run the class with the specified installation when the class file is residing in the current directory and does not use a named package. Which you could find out in less than a minute by just trying. Still, it’s recommended to learn the concepts of class paths and packages.